# How to create a square button?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Thanks for @Justin XL and @grek40 help me so much.
I must apologize for my poor English that troubles everyone so much.
And I think I need to improve this question to help any others in the furture.

Here is the newest:
I need to make a square button like this:
[image]

My programme is a fullscreen programme that different device has different window's size.
So my square button should be can resizeable also beaucase I want to make a Reactive UI.
And now how can I make a square button?
Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have to use binding? It's so simple to do this in code-behind.

Comment: @JustinXL I want to make a ReactiveUI,I think binding is the best choice.If there is a better choice,would you please help me?thank you.

Comment: See my answer below. BTW, I think you should update your question with some of your comments down below, what you really want is a square button, but your title and content didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Rectangle.Stretch` property:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Stretch="Uniform"></Rectangle>
```

I think this answers the actual question of creating a rectangle where width and height are the same and the rectangle is stretched to the available space.

In terms of binding, a `MultiBinding` on both `Width` and `Height` with an `IMultiValueConverter` implementation that returns the minimum of all input values might work. However, it's only needed for controls that don't provide automated stretching.

---

You can use attached properties to set the same width/height for a given limit:

```
public static class SquareSize
{
    public static double GetWidthLimit(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(WidthLimitProperty);
    }

    public static void SetWidthLimit(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(WidthLimitProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthLimitProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "WidthLimit", typeof(double), typeof(SquareSize),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnWidthLimitChanged)));

    private static void OnWidthLimitChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateSize(d, (double)e.NewValue, GetHeightLimit(d));
    }



    public static double GetHeightLimit(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(HeightLimitProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeightLimit(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeightLimitProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeightLimitProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "HeightLimit", typeof(double), typeof(SquareSize),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHeightLimitChanged)));

    private static void OnHeightLimitChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateSize(d, GetWidthLimit(d), (double)e.NewValue);
    }



    private static void UpdateSize(DependencyObject d, double widthLimit, double heightLimit)
    {
        double resultSize = Math.Min(widthLimit, heightLimit);
        d.SetCurrentValue(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, resultSize);
        d.SetCurrentValue(FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, resultSize);
    }
}
```

Use with appropriate xmlns namespace

```
<Border x:Name="border" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Rectangle
        Fill="Red"
        local:SquareSize.WidthLimit="{Binding ElementName=border,Path=ActualWidth}"
        local:SquareSize.HeightLimit="{Binding ElementName=border,Path=ActualHeight}"/>
</Border>
```

---

A solution involving a custom control as wrapper for square-spaced content:

```
public class SquareContentControl : ContentControl
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        var sizeLimit = Math.Min(arrangeBounds.Width, arrangeBounds.Height);
        if (VisualChildrenCount > 0)
        {
            var child = GetVisualChild(0) as UIElement;
            if (child != null)
            {
                child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point((arrangeBounds.Width - sizeLimit) / 2, (arrangeBounds.Height - sizeLimit) / 2), new Size(sizeLimit, sizeLimit)));
                return arrangeBounds;
            }
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        var sizeLimit = Math.Min(constraint.Width, constraint.Height);
        if (VisualChildrenCount > 0)
        {
            var child = GetVisualChild(0) as UIElement;
            if (child != null)
            {
                child.Measure(new Size(sizeLimit, sizeLimit));
                return child.DesiredSize;
            }
        }
        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<Border x:Name="border" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <local:SquareContentControl>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
    </local:SquareContentControl>
</Border>
```

Comment: Set the Stretch="Uniform" works,but a new problem occur.The Rectangle HorizontalAlignment is not center,whenever I set the HorizontalAlignment center,the width of Rectangle turn to be zero.

Comment: As you said,maybe I need learn more about the IMultiValueConverter to achieve this.Haha

Comment: @MelonNG The problem seems to be, `Stretch="Uniform"` targets the `Fill` content rather than the `Rectangle` itself. I could edit with information how to center a Background/Fill content, but that won't help for other types of content - if you provide more information I might have another solution.

Comment: I wanna to make a metro button like this:https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/107926-image/Windows-8.1-update-1-to-boot-into-desktop-by-default-and-have-minimizeclose-buttons-option-for-Metro-apps.jpg  ,so that I need to make sure the button is a square.What's more,my programme is a fullscreen programme,different resolution device has different size metro button,so I need to resize it.

Comment: @MelonNG Can you update your question with the xaml that creates a button for two fixed example sizes, so it becomes clear how you want the button contents to change depending on the size?

Comment: @ grek40 Thanks for help. I updated the question.But I don't know whether it is you need.I am very sorry about my poor English.

Comment: @MelonNG thats not really it... I mean the XAML of a button, not some code behind. For example, if you have an `Image` instead of `Rectangle`, the `Stretch` solution will perfectly work as far as I can see, so it's important to know what you actually have in place of the `Rectangle`.

Comment: @MelonNG added solutions to produce square content with attached properties or with custom control. As you see, there are many different ways to produce and position a square (there are more than the few I mentioned) and if you don't show more details about your button content/layout, there is no way to advise you on the best suited method.

Comment: I am very very sorry for my poor presentation skill.The solution  you and @Justin XL showed is what I need.As Justin XL said,I just need a square button.But I said too much unrelated.I am sorry to trouble you so much.Sorry...

Comment: @MelonNG no need to be sorry, the question wasn't to bad. Just keep improving and when you ask next question, try to separate your requirements (square button) from your attempted solution (compare in binding).

Comment: I just edit the question and correct the requirement.I hope maybe it can help anyone else in the furture.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly fine to have **pure** UI logic like this live inside its code-behind. I'd even argue it's more efficient in most cases.

In your example, it's super easy to square your `Rectangle` with the following code

**XAML**

```
<Border x:Name="MyBorder"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        SizeChanged="MyBorder_SizeChanged">
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle"
               Fill="LightBlue" />
</Border>
```

**Code-behind**

```
private void MyBorder_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyBorder.ActualWidth > MyBorder.ActualHeight)
    {
        MyRectangle.Width = MyRectangle.Height = MyBorder.ActualHeight;
    }
    else if (MyBorder.ActualWidth < MyBorder.ActualHeight)
    {
        MyRectangle.Height = MyRectangle.Height = MyBorder.ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

---

But can we improve this? Since you want a square `Button`, it makes most sense to create a `SquareButton` and insert it straight into your `Grid`.

So the XAML can be simplified to a much more readable version below

```
<local:SquareButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Then you just need to implement the custom control like the following

**`SquareButton` class**

```
[TemplatePart(Name = PART_Root, Type = typeof(Border))]
[TemplatePart(Name = PART_ContentHost, Type = typeof(Border))]
public sealed class SquareButton : Button
{
    private const string PART_Root = "Root";
    private const string PART_ContentHost = "ContentHost";

    public SquareButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(SquareButton);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var root = (Border)GetTemplateChild(PART_Root);
        var contentHost = (Border)GetTemplateChild(PART_ContentHost);

        root.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (root.ActualWidth > root.ActualHeight)
            {
                contentHost.Width = contentHost.Height = root.ActualHeight;
            }
            else if (root.ActualWidth < root.ActualHeight)
            {
                contentHost.Height = contentHost.Height = root.ActualWidth;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**`SquareButton` Style inside `Themes/Generic.xaml`**

```
<Style TargetType="local:SquareButton">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="8,4,8,4" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SquareButton">
                <Border x:Name="Root">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentHost" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentHost" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentHost"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentHost" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentHost"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ContentHost" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just edit the question and correct the requirement.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2017/8/17 only works on WPF, not UWP.

Using Minimum Converter:

```
public class MinConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double result = double.NaN;
        if (values != null)
        {
            try
            {
                result = values.Cast<double>().Aggregate(double.PositiveInfinity, (a, b) => Math.Min(a, b));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                result = double.NaN;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then in your xaml set the Rectangle Height to match parent's Border Min(ActualHeight, ActualWidth). And the Rectangle Width can just bind to Rectangle's ActualHeight

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.8*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="Bd" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Rectangle x:Name="R"
                   Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
           <Rectangle.Height>
              <MultiBinding Converter="converter:MinConverter">
                 <Binding ElementName="Bd" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                 <Binding ElementName="Bd" Path="ActualWidth"/>
              </MultiBinding>
           </Rectangle.Height>
        </Rectangle>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The question was updated already, are you sure your `MultiBinding` works with UWP even though this is explicitely denied in the question?

Comment: Thank you for help sir.But as grek40 said,microsoft has canceled MultiBinding in UWP.